# How to check if a value in a dataframe's column is in another dataframe's column with group by

Tags: python, pandas

What I want to do is:
1- Group the dataframe by two columns
2- From each group, check if the values of a column are not in another column of the group.

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,1,1,1,1,1,2], 'y': [4,4,4,5,5,5,4], 'z':['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a'], 's':['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b']})
x:
    x   y   z   s
0   1   4   a   a
1   1   4   b   a
2   1   4   c   b
3   1   5   a   a
4   1   5   b   a
5   1   5   c   a
6   2   4   a   b
```

What I would like to check is if the values of column `z` are not in column `s` being the dataframe grouped by `x` and `y`.

For example, in the following group (x=1 and y=4):

```
    x   y   z   s
0   1   4   a   a
1   1   4   b   a
2   1   4   c   b
```

The result will be the third row:

```
    x   y   z   s
0   1   4   c   b
```

I have tried something like this but it gets stuck:

```
x= x.groupby(['x', 'y'])[(~x.z.isin(x.s)).index]
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Left merge:

```
m = x.merge(x, left_on=['x','y','z'], 
            right_on=['x','y','s'], 
            how='left', suffixes=['','_']
           )
```

You would see:

```
   x  y  z  s   z_   s_
0  1  4  a  a    a    a
1  1  4  a  a    b    a
2  1  4  b  a    c    b
3  1  4  c  b  NaN  NaN
4  1  5  a  a    a    a
5  1  5  a  a    b    a
6  1  5  a  a    c    a
7  1  5  b  a  NaN  NaN
8  1  5  c  a  NaN  NaN
9  2  4  a  b  NaN  NaN
```

Then your data is where `s_` is `NaN`, so

```
m.loc[m['s_'].isna(), x.columns]
```

Output:

```
   x  y  z  s
3  1  4  c  b
7  1  5  b  a
8  1  5  c  a
9  2  4  a  b
```

---

**Option 2**: do an `apply` with `isin` on `groupby`:

```
(x.groupby(['x','y'])
  .apply(lambda d: d[~d['z'].isin(d['s'])])
  .reset_index(level=['x','y'], drop=True)
)
```

Output:

```
   x  y  z  s
2  1  4  c  b
4  1  5  b  a
5  1  5  c  a
6  2  4  a  b
```

Comment: Brilliant @Quang! First option did it. I then filtered like:
x= x[x.s_.isna()]
Thanks a lot!